# R read.table() adding ï.. in the header

Tags: r, excel, read.table

Several of my students are having the same issue and I cannot figure out why and how.

When importing a csv file in R with `read.table()`, they get `ï..` added at the beginning of the header.

Example:

```
> cars.df <- read.table("cars.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";", dec = ",")
> head(cars.df)
  ï..speed distance
1     4        2
2     4       10
3     7        4
4     7       22
```

It seems that this happens only with students using Microsoft Excel to read csv files. I am not sure if it makes sense, but could that be an encoding issue?

Thanks!

Edit: seems that the issue is also happening with other importing functions like read_delim or read_csv

Comment: It is an encoding issue.  In Excel there are several ways to save a CSV (IIRC they are like unicode, ASCII, MS-DOS, etc), try saving with all the different options and see which one doesn't cause that problem.

Comment: Ok thanks! I cannot test it myself as I don't have this issue. I'll see with the students if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found the issue, and I am posting in case it is useful to anyone.

Turns out some students were saving in csv (coma separated) but then changing the separator as semicolon to avoid confusion with the decimal coma (they have european settings on their computer). Saving as csv (semicolon) solved the issue.

Basically:

- If you are using excel with european settings (coma as decimal), use
  european csv -> semicolon separated
- If you are using excel with north    american settings (decimal
  point), use american csv -> coma separated